# How do React form element get the event parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form component like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>message</legend>
          <label htmlFor="comment-box">content：</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="comment-box"
            placeholder="please enter the message"
            onChange={(event) => { this.handleChange(event); }}
            value={this.state.value}
          />
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

For the input element, I use the arrow function to bind the onChange event, and pass the `event` parameter, so I can get `event` in the `handleChange` function. And if I use the `bind` method to bind `this` in the `constructor`, I found that I don't need to pass the `event` parameter and I can get it in the `handleChange` function too. I wonder why I don't need to explicitly pass the `event` parameter when using the `bind` method?
When using `bind` method to bind this, the code is like:

```js
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        ...
          <input
            type="text"
            id="comment-box"
            placeholder="please enter the message"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.value}
          />
        ...
      </form>
    )
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  ...
}

export default CommentBox;
```

PS:I had ignore the code same to former.

And there is another question.
I had log some value in the `handleChange` method.

```js
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('event.target', event.target);
    console.log('event.target.value', event.target.value);

    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

but the result made me feel confused.
the first log result shows thst the value of `target` of `event` is `null`, but the second and third log result is that they both have the right value. So I wonder whether this is because `React` has defined the `getter` method of `event target`?
PS: I am sorry, actually I want to show picture of the result, but I found that I don't have 10 reputation.

This is my first time asking a question in stackoverflow, any helpful reply be grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that a global event manager passes the event object when it executes callbacks in the queue for that event.

Event is the first parameter of the event callback function, so the registered `onChange` will be invoked with `event` as the first parameter, regardless of whether you bind your function. If you just pass the reference to your function, it will still be called with the event object. The problem is that your function, when executed, won't have the same `this` for `this.setState`.

Something is wrong with your console / debugging code, because both cases should log the event object.

---

Bind means that the calling context `this` will be the context you bind it to. Arrow function binds the context too. Pretty much — onChange adds that function to a queue of handlers, but the window scope (or whatever calls them all) isn’t the same context as your class instance.

In your handler, if you use `this.setState` that function doesn’t exist as part of the `window` or whatever React event queue manager is.

You also have to bind specific parameters like `data-which-field` or re-assign that function every time `onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, whichField)}`

Alternative is `handleChange = event => {` instead of `handleChange(event){` which won’t have `this` bound by default